# Undefined variable in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Please help me in this...I am learning CodeIgniter and i got stuck on this error.There must be some silly mistake.
I am using xampp software for this.
It keeps popping undefined variable rows.

table name is 'user' 
view file name is try
model file name is trydb
controller file name is condb

**ERROR**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: rows

Filename: views/try.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciagain\application\views\try.php
Line: 12
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciagain\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 27
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciagain\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/try.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciagain\application\views\try.php
Line: 12
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciagain\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 27
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciagain\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

**View File**

```
<title>
Connecting data base
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
foreach($rows as $r){
echo $r->ID;
echo $r->Name;    
}

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Modal File**

```
<?php

    class Site_model extends Model {

        function getAll() {
            $q = $this->db->get('user');

            if($q->num_rows()>0) {
                foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
            return $data;
            }
        }


        }
        ?>
```

**Controller file**

```
<?php

class Site extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        $this->load->model('trydb');
        $data['rows'] = $this->trydb->getAll();

        $this->load->view('try', $data);
    }

}
?>
```

**Default controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    public function tryagain(){

     $this->load->view('try');   
    }
}
```

Comment: you model file name is `Site_model`, why are you loading `trydb` ?

Comment: @Dray Ok thanks but still its not working.Do i need to do some changes in config folder files because i am doing it for the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why has you put foreach loop in model? you can use this:

```
function getAll() {
        $q = $this->db->get('user');
        $data = $q->result();
        return $data;
        }
```

and as suggested by DS9 , use below in view files.

```
if(isset($rows) && sizeof($rows)>0)
{
    foreach($rows as $r)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but i am still getting the same notice.Do i have to edit config folder files for the first time to connect to database?

Comment: Check updated code and let me know if any notice occured.

Comment: I have updated the code but there is no any output printed from my user table.(without any notice)

Comment: I have rechecked your code. You used this code:  Site_model extends Model..  You should use site_model extends CI_Model in recent versions of codeigniter.  and can you post url? Are you really load view file try.php?

Comment: I already checked this-site_model extends CI_Model...but  still its not working

Comment: try this url : --  localhost/ciagain/index.php/site/index

Comment: That is not working....but look in controller file and default controller i am loading view i.e try twice.

Comment: Use your index function code of site controller inside tryagain function of Default controller.

Comment: Again no any data is getting displayed from table.(without notice)

Comment: You should read codeigniter documentation properly.  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/welcome.html

Answer (score 1):

It is not `error`, it is a notice

> Severity: Notice

To resolve this you can defined the variable or disable the notice. Prefer first one.

like,

```
if(sizeof($rows)>0)
{
    foreach($rows as $r){
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but value of $data is being passed from from controller to view,hoe can i create that variable.I think there is something wrong with my code of controller file.

Answer (score 0):

Delete space between } and ?> on line 12. It will help. Also there is no Codeigniter 4 :)